# filewatcher for newly created or altered file

Tags: c#, winforms

How do you check for a newly created file. This only works for an edited file.

```
        DateTime time = DateTime.Now;             // Use current time
        string format = "dMyyyy";            // Use this format
        string s = time.ToString(format); 



        fileSystemWatcher1.Path = @"C:\Users\Desktop\test\";
        fileSystemWatcher1.NotifyFilter =   NotifyFilters.LastAccess | 
                                            NotifyFilters.LastWrite | 
                                            NotifyFilters.FileName | 
                                            NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;

        fileSystemWatcher1.IncludeSubdirectories = false;
        fileSystemWatcher1.Filter = s + ".txt";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the example outlined in this article [C#: Application to Watch a File or Directory using FileSystem Watcher](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26528/C-Application-to-Watch-a-File-or-Directory-using-F)

You need to describe what has to be done when one of these attributes in `fileSystemWatcher1.NotifyFilter` gets altered by assigning different event handlers to different activities. For example:

```
fileSystemWatcher1.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
fileSystemWatcher1.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
fileSystemWatcher1.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
fileSystemWatcher1.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(OnRenamed);
```

With the signatures of both the handlers as

```
void OnChanged(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
void OnRenamed(object sender, RenamedEventArgs e)
```

Example handler for `OnChanged`

```
public static void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
   Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1} {2}", s, e.FullPath, e.ChangeType);
}
```

And then enable the watcher to raise events:

```
fileSystemWatcher1EnableRaisingEvents = true;
```

Comment: Additional Note: Don't forget to use `InternalBufferSize` Property. If there are many changes in a short time, the `FileSystemWatcher` Buffer can overflow. This causes the `FileSystemWatcher` to lose track of changes in the `Directory`. See MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.internalbuffersize.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NotifyFilters.CreationTime` for new created files as well.

[NotifyFilters Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.notifyfilters.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

The [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) is really clear on this

```
// Add event handlers.
fileSystemWatcher1.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);

// Enable the event to be raised
fileSystemWatcher1.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

// In the event handler check the change type
private static void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    // Specify what is done when a file is changed, created, or deleted.
   Console.WriteLine("File: " +  e.FullPath + " " + e.ChangeType);
}
```

As you can see from this other page the e.[ChangeType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t6xf43e0%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) enum includes a Created value

Answer (score 0):

The above should work, provided you have added an event handler for fileSystemWatcher1.Created